# Why validation layer doesn't say me I forgot to destroy a device or a surface?

Tags: vulkan

I added `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation` validation layers to my instance. Next I created a debug callback and other vulkan objects. For the test case the only object I'm clearing is the instance (because validation layers should report on instance destruction). And from all of the objects I have the layer reports only about `VkDebugReportCallbackEXT`:

> validation layer: Debug Report callbacks not removed before
>   DestroyInstance

Why it doesn't say me about `VkSurfaceKHR` and `VkDevice` (they are created for sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of it [was fixed](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/issues/2097) in head, but not yet released as SDK.

Other thing is that `vkDestroyInstance` related messages can only be reported through temporary debug report callback provided through `pNext` of `vkCreateInstance`. The reason is all the child objects must be destroyed before `vkDestroyInstance`, including your debug callback, so it is not usable during `vkDestroyInstance`.

So, also chain your `VkDebugReportCallbackCreateInfoEXT` to the `pNext` chain of `vkCreateInstance`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the temporary debug report callback trick but still the maximum I get is four messages about leacked debug callback. But if you say it was fixed I'll wait. P.S.: where can I read about that temporary callback? Documentation says nothing about it, but says `pNext` should be `NULL`.

Comment: Or you can try to build it yourself... ;; You can read about it [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-VkInstanceCreateInfo-pNext-pNext), and [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#_examples_14).