# Minimal Vulkan example of VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT usage doesn't output anything?

Tags: vulkan

The following Vulkan program attempts to create an instance and setup a VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT - but when run it doesn't output anything:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>

VkBool32 VKAPI_PTR debug_utils_messenger_callback(
    VkDebugUtilsMessageSeverityFlagBitsEXT           messageSeverity,
    VkDebugUtilsMessageTypeFlagsEXT                  messageType,
    const VkDebugUtilsMessengerCallbackDataEXT*      pCallbackData,
    void*                                            pUserData) {
  printf("%s", pCallbackData->pMessage);
  return VK_FALSE;
}

int main() {
  // create instance
  VkInstanceCreateInfo instance_create_info = {};
  instance_create_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
  const char* layers[] = {"VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation"};
  instance_create_info.ppEnabledLayerNames = layers;
  instance_create_info.enabledLayerCount = 1;
  const char* extensions[] = {VK_EXT_DEBUG_UTILS_EXTENSION_NAME};
  instance_create_info.enabledExtensionCount = 1;
  instance_create_info.ppEnabledExtensionNames = extensions;
  VkInstance instance;
  if (VK_SUCCESS != vkCreateInstance(&instance_create_info, NULL, &instance))
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  // load kCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT
  PFN_vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT pvkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT =
     (PFN_vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT)
     vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instance, "vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT");
  if (pvkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT == NULL)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  // create debug utils messenger
  VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT debug_utils_messenger_create_info = {};
  debug_utils_messenger_create_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSENGER_CREATE_INFO_EXT;
  debug_utils_messenger_create_info.messageSeverity =
      VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_ERROR_BIT_EXT |
      VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_WARNING_BIT_EXT |
      VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_INFO_BIT_EXT |
      VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_VERBOSE_BIT_EXT;
  debug_utils_messenger_create_info.messageType =
      VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_TYPE_GENERAL_BIT_EXT |
      VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_TYPE_PERFORMANCE_BIT_EXT |
      VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_TYPE_VALIDATION_BIT_EXT;
  debug_utils_messenger_create_info.pfnUserCallback = debug_utils_messenger_callback;
  VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT debug_utils_messenger;
  if (VK_SUCCESS != pvkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(instance, &debug_utils_messenger_create_info, NULL, &debug_utils_messenger))
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  // destroy instance
  vkDestroyInstance(instance, NULL);
}
```

Why not?  I would expect that it outputs some debug messages from the `debug_utils_messenger_callback`?

Comment: Do you actually do anything that would generate messages? Because right after setting up the callback, you destroy the instance and terminate the app. What message are you expecting to see?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Shouldn't I see at least "validation layer: Debug messengers not destroyed before DestroyInstance" ?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos Reporting that would require the `vkCreateInstance->pNext` version of the messenger.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why validation layer doesn't say me I forgot to destroy a device or a surface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47670221/why-validation-layer-doesnt-say-me-i-forgot-to-destroy-a-device-or-a-surface)

Answer (score 1):

Object Tracker does track debug utils objects, but it looks like the layer is only reporting objects belonging to undestroyed device objects at DestroyInstance-time, and debugutils shows up in that list.  It should go in a separate Instance object list and get spit out at DestroyInstance time.

A github issue has been submitted: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-ValidationLayers/issues/658